# Youtube video search went wrong (total constant mismatch)

Tags: youtube-api, bots, discord, discord.js, youtube-javascript-api

first, tbh Im still not familiar with all of this but I still decided to give it a try, so pls be patient with me here.

the package Im using here is discord.js Commando and discord-youtube-api. before I add the play function, I decided to see if I can get the search function right. But everytime I tried to search for something, the result is a total nonsense (not even a single relation to the video I tried to search) and its only giving me one result (watch?v=-yDd2D5OHyc) and nothing else.

```
class SearchCommand extends Commando.Command {
    constructor(client){
        super(client,{
            name: 'search',
            group:'music',
            memberName:'search',
            description: 'Search a Youtube video',
            args: [
                {
                    key: 'text',
                    prompt: 'Input the video name?',
                    type: 'string'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    async run (message, args, {text})
    {
        message.channel.send(args)
        message.channel.send(text)
        var video = await youtube.searchVideos(args.toString().replace(/,/g,' '));
        message.channel.send(video.url);
        message.channel.send(video.thumbnail);
        message.channel.send(video.length);

    }
}

module.exports = SearchCommand;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks slothiful for the answer to my problem.
while your solution is correct for the questioned problem, another error occured

```
(node:14492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object
```

But, the presented solution is not wrong. It's just incomplete.
Fortunately, I've found the solution for the new error, and combined with your solution, I can make it work like this

```
async run(message, {text})
    {
        const args = text.split(/ +/g);
        const video = await youtube.searchVideos(args);
        console.log(args.toString());
        console.log(args.join(' '));
        console.log(video.url)
        const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
        if (message.member.voiceChannel){
        message.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(
            connection => { 
            const stream = yt(video.url, { filter : 'audioandvideo', quality : 'highestaudio', lang : 'en'});
            const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
            })
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send("Please join a voice channel before I can play it for you !")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...it[']s only giving me one result...

This is the expected behavior of the `searchVideos()` method according to the [package's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-youtube-api).

---

> [T]he result is a total nonsense...

[`Array.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) will join the elements of the array with a comma. This could be leading to your unexpected result.

You can join the `args` array together with [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and use a space as a delimiter rather than a comma. Consider this example...

```js
const text = 'baby shark 10 hours';
const args = text.split(/ +/g);

console.log(args.toString());  // Your current search query
console.log(args.join(' '));   // The expected search query
```